# get month Number from month name in groovy

Tags: date, groovy

is there a built-in function or API i can use to convert month name like FEB, February to month number 02?

I'm passing from the view to the controller.

Answer (score 8):

Call `Date.parse` with `MMM` as the format string.  This will give you a Date object which provides access to the month number.  Example:

```
def d = Date.parse('MMM', 'Feb')
def num = d.format('MM') as int
assert num == 2
```

Comment: Great escape from the hellish Java convention of months starting from 0!

Answer (score 1):

You can parse month names to dates with the regular parse function of `Date`:

```
new Date().parse("MMM", "Feb")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
String monthString = 'Feb'

int month = Calendar.instance.with {
  time = new Date().parse( "MMM", monthString )
  it[ MONTH ]
}

// Feb is 1 of course, not 2 as in your question
assert month == 1
```